# Why does z-index not work in text, even though it is set?

Tags: javascript, html, css, z-index

So, I have this example of an html form:

```js
              function submit(){
                document.getElementById('load').style.width = "80%";
              }
```

```css
            .load{
                border-radius:12px;
                background-color:#00ff88;
                height:80%;
                position:relative;
                z-index:2;
                top:0;
                display:block;
                width:0;
                transition: 1.5s ease-in;
                margin:5% auto 15% auto;
                position:fixed;
                top:2.5%;
                left:10%;
            }
            .load:hover{
                border-radius: 8px;
            }        
body {font-family: Noto Sans, IBM Plex Sans Condensed; overflow:hidden;}
* {box-sizing: border-box;

/* Set a style for all buttons */
button {
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.9;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  outline-style: solid;
  outline-width:1px;
}

button:hover {
  border-radius: 5px;
  opacity:1;
}

/* Extra styles for the cancel button */
.cancelbtn {
  padding: 14px 20px;
  background-color: #f44336;
}

/* Float cancel and signup buttons and add an equal width */
.cancelbtn, .signupbtn, .refreshbtn {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Add padding to container elements */
.container {
  padding: 16px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 40px -1px rgba(10,10,10,0.74);
  transition: .6s ease;
}
.container:hover {
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 40px -3px rgba(10,10,10,0.74);
  border-radius: 5px;
}
  .clearfix > p{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:15%;
    left:40%;
    margin-top: 0%;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  #options{
    overflow-y:scroll;
  }
}
```

```html
        <div class="center load" id="load" style="position: absolute"></div>
        <div class="container modal-content" style="height:80%;max-height:100%;position:fixed;top:2.5%;left:10%;z-index:1;" id="quiz">
            <div id="content" style="z-index: 50;position:relative;background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)">
                <h1 id="Qtitle">Example Poll [title]</h1>
                <hr>
                
                <div id="options" style="display: block;">
                
                <p style="font-size:20px;" onclick="select('option1')"><input type="radio" name="cXVlc3Rpbwo" value="1" id="option1"><label style="cursor:pointer;" for="cXVlc3Rpbwo" id="first" onclick="select('option1')"><b>[Option1]</b></label></p>
                
                <p style="font-size:20px;" onclick="select('option2')"><input type="radio" name="cXVlc3Rpbwo" value="2" id="option2"><label style="cursor:pointer;" for="cXVlc3Rpbwo" id="second" onclick="select('option2')"><b>[Option2]</b></label></p>
                
                <p style="font-size:20px;" onclick="select('option3')"><input type="radio" name="cXVlc3Rpbwo" value="3" id="option3"><label style="cursor:pointer;" for="cXVlc3Rpbwo" id="third" onclick="select('option3')"><b>[Option3]</b></label></p>
                
                <p style="font-size:20px;" onclick="select('option4')"><input type="radio" name="cXVlc3Rpbwo" value="4" id="option4"><label style="cursor:pointer;" for="cXVlc3Rpbwo" id="fourth" onclick="select('option4')"><b>[Option4]</b></label></p>
                
                </div>
            
                <input name="UUNvZGU" style="display:none;" id="QCode" value="error">
                <br>
            
                <hr>
            
                <div class="clearfix" style="margin-bottom:50%;margin-top:0%;">
                  <button class="signupbtn" onclick="submit()" id="submit">Vote</button>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <script>
              function submit(){
                document.getElementById('load').style.width = "80%";
              }
          </script>
```

As you can see, even though the back div's z-index is 1, the green div's is 2 and the text's is 50, the green div grows over the text.

Any suggestions?

(Sorry for the terrible snippet quality, but, my project is 3000 lines long and I got a bit confused. Please run the snippet in full screen instead).

Answer (score 0):

If you give the green div a z-index that is lower than the z-index of the form, then everything should work as you wanted.

I gave the green div a `height` and a `width` too see it. Then i gave it a `z-index` of 0 (Remove the `height`and the `width`!!! I just added that to show)

**Here's an image of what i added:**

[image: Added]

**Here is how it looks like now:**

[image: Code]

**Here's the code:**

```css
.load{
                border-radius:12px;
                background-color:#00ff88;
                height:80%;
                position:relative;
                z-index:2;
                top:0;
                display:block;
                width:0;
                transition: 1.5s ease-in;
                margin:5% auto 15% auto;
                position:fixed;
                top:2.5%;
                left:10%;
                /* I gave the green div a height and a width too see it */
                height: 100px;
                width: 100px;
                /* z-index for the green Div */
                z-index: 0;
                
            }
            .load:hover{
                border-radius: 8px;
            }        
body {font-family: Noto Sans, IBM Plex Sans Condensed; overflow:hidden;}
* {box-sizing: border-box;

/* Set a style for all buttons */
button {
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.9;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  outline-style: solid;
  outline-width:1px;
}

button:hover {
  border-radius: 5px;
  opacity:1;
}

/* Extra styles for the cancel button */
.cancelbtn {
  padding: 14px 20px;
  background-color: #f44336;
}

/* Float cancel and signup buttons and add an equal width */
.cancelbtn, .signupbtn, .refreshbtn {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Add padding to container elements */
.container {
  padding: 16px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 40px -1px rgba(10,10,10,0.74);
  transition: .6s ease;
}
.container:hover {
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 40px -3px rgba(10,10,10,0.74);
  border-radius: 5px;
}
  .clearfix > p{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:15%;
    left:40%;
    margin-top: 0%;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  #options{
    overflow-y:scroll;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="center load" id="load" style="position: absolute"></div>
        <div class="container modal-content" style="height:80%;max-height:100%;position:fixed;top:2.5%;left:10%;z-index:1;" id="quiz">
            <div id="content" style="z-index: 50;position:relative;background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)">
                <h1 id="Qtitle">Example Poll [title]</h1>
                <hr>
                
                <div id="options" style="display: block;">
                
                <p style="font-size:20px;" onclick="select('option1')"><input type="radio" name="cXVlc3Rpbwo" value="1" id="option1"><label style="cursor:pointer;" for="cXVlc3Rpbwo" id="first" onclick="select('option1')"><b>[Option1]</b></label></p>
                
                <p style="font-size:20px;" onclick="select('option2')"><input type="radio" name="cXVlc3Rpbwo" value="2" id="option2"><label style="cursor:pointer;" for="cXVlc3Rpbwo" id="second" onclick="select('option2')"><b>[Option2]</b></label></p>
                
                <p style="font-size:20px;" onclick="select('option3')"><input type="radio" name="cXVlc3Rpbwo" value="3" id="option3"><label style="cursor:pointer;" for="cXVlc3Rpbwo" id="third" onclick="select('option3')"><b>[Option3]</b></label></p>
                
                <p style="font-size:20px;" onclick="select('option4')"><input type="radio" name="cXVlc3Rpbwo" value="4" id="option4"><label style="cursor:pointer;" for="cXVlc3Rpbwo" id="fourth" onclick="select('option4')"><b>[Option4]</b></label></p>
                
                </div>
            
                <input name="UUNvZGU" style="display:none;" id="QCode" value="error">
                <br>
            
                <hr>
            
                <div class="clearfix" style="margin-bottom:50%;margin-top:0%;">
                  <button class="signupbtn" onclick="submit()" id="submit">Vote</button>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <script>
              function submit(){
                document.getElementById('load').style.width = "80%";
              }
          </script>
```